# Retrieve Shifts Unpaid Breaks using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

When you create a Shift via Microsoft Teams, there is a field for an Unpaid Break in minutes, as shown here:
[Shifts UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AXe8.png)

When this shift is retrieved via Microsoft Graph API, the Unpaid Break field is nowhere to be found.

```
{
"@odata.etag": "\"350013f7-0000-0400-0000-60d4e66a0000\"",
"id": "SHFT_273d6cb6-8a97-4e56-9012-41902a8904d6",
"createdDateTime": "2021-06-24T20:09:14.58Z",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-06-24T20:09:14.58Z",
"schedulingGroupId": "TAG_28cc22dd-65df-4f3f-86aa-f5fcff11da80",
"userId": "fd4be5ff-ceeb-4f6c-8331-4324573d37f8",
"draftShift": null,
"lastModifiedBy": {
"application": null,
"device": null,
"user": {
"id": "fd4be5ff-ceeb-4f6c-8331-4324573d37f8",
"displayName": "",
"userIdentityType": "aadUser"
}
},
"sharedShift": {
"displayName": "Sleep Shift",
"notes": null,
"startDateTime": "2021-06-15T12:00:00Z",
"endDateTime": "2021-06-15T21:00:00Z",
"theme": "blue",
"activities": []
}
}
```

I've tried the /teams/{teamId}/schedule/shifts and /teams/{teamId}/schedule/timesOff endpoints.

How do you retrieve the Unpaid Break value via Microsoft Graph? Is there a different endpoint I should be using?

Comment: Hey@Rishan-EIT, We tried to repro at our end and can confirm that 'Unpaid Break field' is not getting reflected in response. We are checking this internally with concerned team and will get back to you once we get any update. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to get 'Unpaid Break field' in response using Graph API. This will only be available in UI.